# How to override default Android's default screen lock security policy?

Tags: security, vpn

I want my Android device screen to open without requiring password. So I chose "none" option in Security settings. But, when I needed to add a VPN connection, it required me to provide a password, PIN, or a pattern for the screen. Thus, the option to add "none" unlock is disabled once a VPN connection is set (figure below).
[image]

I want to know if there is a way I can override this security policy i.e. retain VPN connection but forego screen unlock password. The Android version is 4.2 and the tablet is rooted if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of ways (None of these tried by me)

- This XDA thread [HOW TO GUIDE VPN Without Security](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2666126) suggests a way of editing lock screen database settings using SQL editor . OP has specifically tested on Kitkat
- You could try Xposed module [Lockscreen Disabler](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.lr.keyguarddisabler). Module description says

> To setup a VPN you are forced by the system to setup some kind of security.
>
> This module is for all the users who don't want to be forced to use a protection, although using the services described above

If you are not familiar with Xposed, [Xposed: The mighty Android tool box](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/xposed-intro) by @Izzy, would be very useful

- [VpnROOT-PPTP-Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.did.vpnroot) claims to do that, amongst other capabilities. App description says

  > This application was designed to allow connection of a VPN server without having to use PIN or Pattern Lock-Screen in Android.

**Edit:** The first method did not work for me on 4.2.2 (tried after posting this answer).